# Получение ссылки на координаты в iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, карты

Реализую функцию отправки моих координат по смс. Отправка сообщения удается, а вот отправка координат не очень. Не пойму как создать ссылку с координатами. Хотелось бы следующее: получаю свои координаты, группирую каким-то образом ссылку и отправляю ее по смс, пользователь нажимает на ссылку и открывается стандартная карта с моим местоположением.

Получить свои координаты не сложно, но каким образом правильно их получать для составления ссылки я не знаю, подскажите пожалуйста.

Вот то, что я пробовал из последнего:

```
      @IBAction func sendMessage(sender: AnyObject) {

    let messageVC = MFMessageComposeViewController()

    var lat1 : NSString = String(self.venueLat)
    var lng1 : NSString = String(self.venueLng)

    var latitute:CLLocationDegrees =  lat1.doubleValue
    var longitute:CLLocationDegrees =  lng1.doubleValue

    let regionDistance:CLLocationDistance = 10000
    var coordinates = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(latitute, longitute)
    let regionSpan = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(coordinates, regionDistance, regionDistance)
    var options = [
        MKLaunchOptionsMapCenterKey: NSValue(MKCoordinate: regionSpan.center),
        MKLaunchOptionsMapSpanKey: NSValue(MKCoordinateSpan: regionSpan.span)
    ]

    var placemark = MKPlacemark(coordinate: coordinates, addressDictionary: nil)

    var mapItem = MKMapItem(placemark: placemark)


    messageVC.body =  String(mapItem) //"Enter a message";

    messageVC.recipients = ["Enter tel-nr"]
    messageVC.messageComposeDelegate = self;

    self.presentViewController(messageVC, animated: false, completion: nil)
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если попробовать отправить адрес напрямую из apple map, он отправится как файл формата `.loc.vcf` - это Vcard. Этот самый файл можно отправить самому себе по емейлу (прямо из apple.maps), чтоб посмотреть что в нем и попробовать сделать такой же (либо поискать готовое решение на github).

Немного проще будет отправить прямой url на карту, вроде такого:

`http://maps.apple.com/maps?ll=4.872000\,114.920000&t=m`

где ll (две маленькие латинские L) это lat и lon (разделены запятой и слэшем; положительные значения - север и восток, если надо юг или запад, поставьте минус перед соответствующим значением). что такое t=m не вникал, без него у меня не заработало. Проблема с таким форматом - на карте нет пина, уверен, что это тоже решаемо.

Comment: Спасибо, отправить ссылку получается, а есть ли возможность присвоить ссылке какое-либо имя? Просто иногда ссылки могут быть больших размеров

Comment: можно через bitly.com сократить или другой подобный сервис.